# How can I check the dex count in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, android-multidex

My project's gradle file is as below.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

I can see DexIndexOverflowException when "Generate Signed APK" in Android Studio.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyProject:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I already know this error and read the document(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).
Just I want to check How many dex has exceeded.

For example:

```
trouble writing output:
Too many field references: 99999; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

Please find a solution.

Comment: If your build fails, there is no APK to count. It's ironic that a method-limit-exceeded failure will prevent the method count from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this plugin to get the number of method references in your APK on every build.

**[dexcount](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin)**

Comment: Can I see dex count when build failed?

Comment: If your build fails, there is no APK to count. It's ironic that a method-limit-exceeded failure will prevent the method count from happening.

Comment: I removed one by one to avoid failing. And I checked total dex count. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio has an [APK analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html) that shows this information, no gradle plugins required.

Comment: But, I want to see when build failed. This analyzer need to apk when generate build succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer#view_dex_files). I was searching for the same and found my answer here. Basicly, you have to generate the APK of your project and then go to Build->Analyze APK and at the rasults click on classes.dex, then, below you will see exactly how many methods are defined and referenced by the project.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio has a plugin called `Android Methods Count` which will show  the number of methods for each of your dependencies.

There's also a cli tool available with more options at
https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts

Comment: Can I see dex count when build failed?

Comment: `Android Methods Count` will display the methods count for each of your dependencies when you hover over them inside your `build,gradle` . The other tool needs your apk file to do so you'll need to remove some dependencies and then check with that. Also check your Proguard settings to see if any unused methods can be removed

Answer (score 0):

I modified dx.jar source to show method count.

https://github.com/b1uec0in/dx

### Output sample

```
string ID count: 91,857
type ID count: 12,636
proto ID count: 18,417
field ID count: 72,011 (max:65535 +6476)
method ID count: 81,181 (max:65535 +15646)
```

replace your dx.jar with this [dx.jar](https://github.com/b1uec0in/dx/releases).